# Using CSS to affect great grand child

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that will stick to the top of the page when it slides, when this happens it adds two classes to the div "sticked in" this works perfectly but what I would like to do is

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm sticked in">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-logo">
             <a href="http://localhost/2021/site/">
                <img src="logo.svg" class="custom-logo">
             </a>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

After it sticks i would like to scale the img (logo.svg) down so what im looking for is the correct selectors for if "sticked in" is on my nav bar change the height of .header-logo img

for example:

```
.sticked.in > div > a > .header-logo img{
    height: 20px;
}
```

obviously, these are the wrong selectors so im looking for a way of going down the css to header-logo img if "sticked in" is present

Comment: I don't know if I understood very well what you want, but isn't it?

`.sticked.in img { height: 20px; }`

Comment: that will work for all images within sticked in so yes your answer is correct and thank you but this could affect any other img's added into nav bar in the future like an icons so would be nice to be a able to target .header-logo so after testing .

sticked.in .header-logo img

will work so please add your comment as answer so i can accept

Comment: Oh, someone else added, I don't think it's worth it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `>` child selector. Example with toggle:

```js
document.getElementById("toggle-class")
        .addEventListener("click", function() 
{
    document.querySelector(".navbar")
            .classList.toggle("sticked");
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sticked.in .custom-logo {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm sticked in">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-logo">
             <a href="http://localhost/2021/site/">
                <img class="custom-logo">
             </a>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>

<button id="toggle-class">Toggle</button>
```